# React Native - Retrieve everything in AsyncStorage except keys?

Tags: javascript, json, react-native, foreach, asyncstorage

Currently, I am using **AsyncStorage.setItem()** to push a string key with a stringified  JSON object to AsyncStorage. i.e:
[image]

As I am retrieving everything in AsyncStorage by using getAllKeys() and multiGet(), I am realizing that I only want to access the objects themselves and have no use for the keys.

What would be the most efficient way for me to only access the stringified objects? My current function in which *element* represents the keys and the values:

```
importData = () => {
  AsyncStorage.getAllKeys().then(keys => AsyncStorage.multiGet(keys)
    .then((result) => {
      result.map(req => req.forEach((element) => {
        this.setState({ favorites: JSON.parse(element) });
        console.log(this.state.favorites);
      }));
    }));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This should get you all the values except for keys. You're gonna want to `JSON.parse()` your data if it's in a hierarchy.

```
  getData = async () => {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.getAllKeys().then(async keys => {
        await AsyncStorage.multiGet(keys).then(key => {
          key.forEach(data => {
            console.log(data[1]); //values
          });
        });
      });
    } catch (error) {
      Alert.alert("Couldn't load data", error);
    }
  };
```